# PhpStorm SQL editor: insert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or now() into date column

Tags: sql, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm adding new rows into database via SQL editor and when I try to add `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into date file, it converts this to a string, the same with function `now()`

[image]

```sql
INSERT INTO x (id, version, data, content_type, start_date, creation_date) VALUES (1, 1, null, 'application/pdf', 'now()', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
[2021-02-26 14:33:04] [22001][1292] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'now()' for column 'start_date' at row 1
```

Is there any way to enforce SQL editor to recognize that this is a function or a constant?

Answer (score 1):

it is impossible at the moment. here is [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7422), please follow and vote.